# How to split a proxy in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to split a proxy with the format "HOST:PORT" and then continue to use the port in a requests. Therefore I need a string and a int. I have tried this:

```
string text = ProxyList.ToString();
string[] array = text.Split(':');
string host = array[0].ToString();
int portParse = Int32.Parse(array[1]);
this.Checker(host, portParse);
string text2 = ProxyList[i];
this.Checker(host, portParse);
```

I keep getting this error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

on this line: `int portParse = Int32.Parse(array[1]);

Thanks Bruno LM

Comment: What is the type and contents of the `ProxyList` variable?

Comment: Run the code in a debugger. See what the values are. I'm guessing `text` doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: Proxylist aka text contains 4 proxies

Comment: 67.207.95.138:8080
98.172.91.132:8080
67.207.95.138:8080
98.172.91.131:8080
1 duplicated and 1 fake proxy.

Comment: What is the content of `text`? Have a look either with debugger or output it to Console. Is there really any : in the variable?

Comment: I fixed the OutOfRangeException now I get a System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Still with above shown text? Is array[1] “8080 98.172.91.132“? You should split at spaces and :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ProxyList` is as you mention, text, then I assume it could be declared like this:

```
string ProxyList = "67.207.95.138:8080 98.172.91.132:8080 67.207.95.138:8080 98.172.91.131:8080";
```

By doing `string[] array = text.Split(':');` you get

```
8080 98.172.91.132
```

If you wanted just a port, then you need first to split by space.

```
string ProxyList = "67.207.95.138:8080 98.172.91.132:8080 67.207.95.138:8080 98.172.91.131:8080";

// split by space
string[] proxies = ProxyList.Split(' ');

// get first host:port 67.207.95.138:8080
string text = proxies[0];

// get the port 8080 (split of the first entry)
string[] array = text.Split(':');

string host = array[0].ToString();
int portParse = Int32.Parse(array[1]); // 8080
```

---

What you can do to execute something with every proxy is this:

```
string input = "67.207.95.138:8080 98.172.91.132:8080 67.207.95.138:8080 98.172.91.131:8080";

var proxies = input.Split(' ')
    .Select(ip => new Uri($"http://{ip}"))
    .Distinct(); // remove duplicates

foreach (var proxy in proxies)
{
    var ip = proxy.Host;
    var port = proxy.Port;

    // do something
}
```

Comment: I want to parse all the proxies in a listbox. But when I try to I continue to get this error. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'